# Moq and validating a private method ios called with correct parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm probably below average on Unit Testing skills, but been asked to write a unit test for something I fixed. Basically, a method now allows a null value to be passed in, and I need to validate that it gets switched to the correct value, if null.(Please note, method code reduced to remove supurfluous code - it actually does more than return true...)

```
 public IDictionary<string, JToken> MethodINeedToTest(
            long? userId,
            long? orgId
        )
 {
       userId ??= DataServicesHelper.SystemUserKey;
            
       var myResults = APrivateMethod(userId.Value, orgId, false);

       return true;
}
```

I was hoping to just verify that `APrivateMethod` was called with the value from `DataServicesHelper.SystemUserKey`. However, the method is private. So with Moq, I cannot do a verify on a private method (I believe).

Is there anyway to validate that when `userId` is passed in as null, the method is called with `DataServicesHelper.SystemUserKey`? (Other test is to validate that it gets called with userId when it's not null).

Or is the code just not testable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case there are 2 options.

1. Just let the `APrivateMethod` execute as is without any mocks and you validate the result that you get in both cases.
2. If option 1 is not possible due to the private method calling any outside service/repository then in that case you should try to use DI to inject those external dependencies that are used by the private method and then mock out those external calls.